# How to perform addition and multiplication in F_{2^8}

Tags: python, finite-field

I want to perform addition and multiplication in F_{2^8}

I currently have this code which seems to work for add but doesn't work for multiply; the issue seems to be that when I modulo by 100011011 (which represents x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1), it doesn't seem to do it. Another idea would be to use numpy.polynomial but it isn't as intuitive.

```
def toBinary(self, n):
    return ''.join(str(1 & int(n) >> i) for i in range(8)[::-1])

def add(self, x, y):
    """
     "10111001" + "10010100" = "00101101"
    """

    if len(x)<8:
        self.add('0'+x,y)
    elif len(y)<8:
        self.add(x,'0'+y)

    try:
        a = int(x,2); b = int(y,2)
        z = int(x)+int(y)
        s = ''
    
        for i in str(z):
            if int(i)%2 == 0:
                s+='0'
            else:
                s+='1'
    except:
        return '00000000'

    return s
    
def multiply(self, x, y):
    """
    "10111001" * "10010100" = "10110010"
    """
    if len(x)<8:
        self.multiply('0'+x,y)
    elif len(y)<8:
        self.multiply(x,'0'+y)

    result = '00000000'

    result = '00000000'
    while y!= '00000000' :
        print(f'x:{x},y:{y},result:{result}')
        if int(y[-1]) == 1 :
            result = self.add(result ,x)
            y = self.add(y, '00000001')
        x = self.add(self.toBinary(int(x,2)<<1),'100011011')
        y = self.toBinary(int(y,2)>>1) #b = self.multiply(b,inverse('00000010'))
    return result
```

Comment: Maybe I am not up on the latest terminology but what is "F_{2^8}"?  Saying code doesn't work for multiply is mot a question. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: F_{2^8} is a Gallois field of 2^8 composed of 8 bits per string, the algorithm I coded is a version of Rijndael's algorithm using modular reduction but this step is failing

Comment: I updated my answer to include a python example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python example for add (same as subtract), multiply, divide, and inverse. Assumes the input parameters are 8 bit values, and there is no check for divide by 0.

```
def add(x, y):                  # add is xor
    return x^y

def sub(x, y):                  # sub is xor
    return x^y

def mpy(x, y):                  # mpy two 8 bit values
    p = 0b100011011             # mpy modulo x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1
    m = 0                       # m will be product
    for i in range(8):
        m = m << 1
        if m & 0b100000000:
            m = m ^ p
        if y & 0b010000000:
            m = m ^ x
        y = y << 1
    return m

def div(x, y):                   # divide using inverse
    return mpy(x, inv(y))        #  (no check for y = 0)

def inv(x):                      # x^254 = 1/x
    p=mpy(x,x)                   # p = x^2
    x=mpy(p,p)                   # x = x^4
    p=mpy(p,x)                   # p = x^(2+4)
    x=mpy(x,x)                   # x = x^8
    p=mpy(p,x)                   # p = x^(2+4+8)
    x=mpy(x,x)                   # x = x^16
    p=mpy(p,x)                   # p = x^(2+4+8+16)
    x=mpy(x,x)                   # x = x^32
    p=mpy(p,x)                   # p = x^(2+4+8+16+32)
    x=mpy(x,x)                   # x = x^64
    p=mpy(p,x)                   # p = x^(2+4+8+16+32+64)
    x=mpy(x,x)                   # x = x^128
    p=mpy(p,x)                   # p = x^(2+4+8+16+32+64+128)
    return p

print hex(add(0b01010101, 0b10101010))      # returns 0xff
print hex(mpy(0b01010101, 0b10101010))      # returns 0x59
print hex(div(0b01011001, 0b10101010))      # returns 0x55
```

---

For GF(2^n), both add and subtract are XOR. This means multiplies are carryless and divides are borrowless. The X86 has a carryless multiply for XMM registers, PCLMULQDQ. Divide by a constant can be done with carryless multiply by 2^64 / constant and using the upper 64 bits of the product. The inverse constant is generated using a loop for borrowless divide.

The reason for this is GF(2^n) elements are polynomials with 1 bit coefficients, (the coefficients are elements of GF(2)).

For GF(2^8), it would be simpler to generate exponentiate and log tables. Example C code:

```c
#define POLY (0x11b)
/* all non-zero elements are powers of 3 for POLY == 0x11b */
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
/* ... */
static BYTE exp2[512];
static BYTE log2[256];
/* ... */
static void Tbli()
{
int i;
int b;
    b = 0x01;                   /* init exp2 table */
    for(i = 0; i < 512; i++){
        exp2[i] = (BYTE)b;
        b = (b << 1) ^ b;       /*  powers of 3 */
        if(b & 0x100)
            b ^= POLY;
    }

    log2[0] = 0xff;             /* init log2 table */
    for(i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        log2[exp2[i]] = (BYTE)i;
}
/* ... */
static BYTE GFMpy(BYTE m0, BYTE m1) /* multiply */
{
    if(0 == m0 || 0 == m1)
        return(0);
    return(exp2[log2[m0] + log2[m1]]);
}
/* ... */
static BYTE GFDiv(BYTE m0, BYTE m1) /* divide */
{
    if(0 == m0)
        return(0);
    return(exp2[log2[m0] + 255 - log2[m1]]);
}
```

Comment: Example C code isn't really useful for a question tagged `python`.

Comment: @chepner - consider it to be psuedocode for Python, and the OP may not want to use tables. The main part of the answer is the text prior to the example code.

Comment: `*(p1+*p0++) = d0;` is not, practically, pseudocode. Making any sense of this requires understanding of the specific syntax and semantics of C, which are vastly different to Python.

Comment: @kaya3 - I updated my answer, using indexes instead of pointers. Also increased size of exp2[] to 512 to speed up the math.

Comment: @chepner - I updated my answer to include python example code.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Python package [galois](https://github.com/mhostetter/galois) that extends NumPy arrays over finite fields. Working with `GF(2^8)` is quite easy, see my below example.

```py
In [1]: import galois

In [2]: GF = galois.GF(2**8, irreducible_poly="x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1")

In [3]: print(GF.properties)
GF(2^8):
  characteristic: 2
  degree: 8
  order: 256
  irreducible_poly: x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1
  is_primitive_poly: False
  primitive_element: x + 1

# Your original values from your example
In [4]: a = GF(0b10111001); a
Out[4]: GF(185, order=2^8)

In [5]: b = GF(0b10010100); b
Out[5]: GF(148, order=2^8)

In [6]: c = a * b; c
Out[6]: GF(178, order=2^8)

# You can display the result as a polynomial over GF(2)
In [7]: GF.display("poly");

# This matches 0b10110010
In [8]: c
Out[8]: GF(x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x, order=2^8)
```

You can work with arrays too.

```py
In [12]: a = GF([1, 2, 3, 4]); a
Out[12]: GF([1, 2, 3, 4], order=2^8)

In [13]: b = GF([100, 110, 120, 130]); b
Out[13]: GF([100, 110, 120, 130], order=2^8)

In [14]: a * b
Out[14]: GF([100, 220, 136,  62], order=2^8)
```

It's open source, so you can review all the code. Here's a snippet of multiplication in `GF(2^m)`. All of the inputs are integers. Here's how to perform the "polynomial multiplication" using integers with characteristic 2.

```py
    def _multiply_calculate(a, b, CHARACTERISTIC, DEGREE, IRREDUCIBLE_POLY):
        """
        a in GF(2^m), can be represented as a degree m-1 polynomial a(x) in GF(2)[x]
        b in GF(2^m), can be represented as a degree m-1 polynomial b(x) in GF(2)[x]
        p(x) in GF(2)[x] with degree m is the irreducible polynomial of GF(2^m)

        a * b = c
            = (a(x) * b(x)) % p(x) in GF(2)
            = c(x)
            = c
        """
        ORDER = CHARACTERISTIC**DEGREE

        # Re-order operands such that a > b so the while loop has less loops
        if b > a:
            a, b = b, a

        c = 0
        while b > 0:
            if b & 0b1:
                c ^= a  # Add a(x) to c(x)

            b >>= 1  # Divide b(x) by x
            a <<= 1  # Multiply a(x) by x
            if a >= ORDER:
                a ^= IRREDUCIBLE_POLY  # Compute a(x) % p(x)

        return c
```

The same example runs as follows.

```py
In [72]: _multiply_calculate(0b10111001, 0b10010100, 2, 8, 0b100011011)
Out[72]: 178

In [73]: bin(_multiply_calculate(0b10111001, 0b10010100, 2, 8, 0b100011011))
Out[73]: '0b10110010'
```